# Not able to set "stringType" to "String" in sbt-avro

Tags: sbt, avro

I'm using sbt-avro plugin in my Play framework project. I use the following code in my build.sbt file -

```
seq(sbtavro.SbtAvro.projectSettings: _*)
(sourceDirectory in avroConfig) := baseDirectory.value / "app/avro"
(stringType in avroConfig) := "String"
```

However, the generated classes have "CharSequence" instead of "String" types. How to change this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

> seq(sbtavro.SbtAvro.projectSettings: _*) (sourceDirectory in
> avroConfig) := baseDirectory.value / "app/avro" (stringType in
> avroConfig) := "String"

use:
avroStringType := "String"

you can see other settings in: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro
and in the example, they use it